# JQuery UI tabs wont save selected tab index upon page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

When I use AJAX or PHP POST the page reloads and the tabs bounce back to index position 0, which is quite annoying. You can find the code below. I am trying to save the tab index in a cookie and use it to return to the selected tab even after the page reloads.

The code is here:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({ axis: "x" });
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $( "#tabs" ).tabs('select', $.cookie("tabNumber"));

       $( "#tabs" ).click(function() {
         $.cookie("tabNumber", $( "#tabs" ).tabs('option', 'selected'));
       });
    });
});
```

Maybe someone can help me to find out how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#option-cookie

Initialize a tabs with the cookie option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30 } });
```

Comment: +1, and here's the official [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/cookie.html)

Comment: I believe the cookie option has been depreciated from recent UI code.

Comment: In that case it is up to the developer to implement a way of storing the last active tab (session, cookies) and set it up on the page using the "active" option described here: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active